# Software Suggestion Question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I am wondering if my question is going to be on-topic.

I am having trouble finding software that is native to linux that can cut STL models in to smaller models for printing properly.  Is asking for help finding software that can do this, or asking for help with some software that I have found, on topic here?

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't think this is off-topic, but I recommend also noting what machine(s) you're trying to slice for as the code can be different depending on the capabilities of the machine.